# OpenStreetMap: need a tile service with English labels in non-English countries

Tags: openstreetmap, tiles

I want to use OpenStreetMap tile server in its QtLocation plugin.

Alas, if I use the host provided by default, there are non-English labels in non-English countries (Arabic, for example).

[image: I don't need Arabian labels, I need English ones = (]

I don't know Arabian, so I need a tile service where there are English labels. Can I get one?

Comment: Have you looked through all the tile options here? http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tiles#Servers

Answer (score 4):

In OpenStreetMap, place names can be edited in several languages. For instance, look at the [capital of China](https://www.openstreetmap.de/karte.html), which is defined in OSM in hundreds of languages (see the name:en, name:fr, name:es, etc. tags) The name that will be rendered in the default OSM tiles is the name under the tag "name", which must be the local name.

This means that one can produce some map tiles using a specific language, for instance, with rendering place names using the name:en tag instead of the name tag (at least if these places are translated in the database).

There are maps in English at [Mapbox here](http://a.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/mapbox/maps.html). See this site https://mc.bbbike.org/mc/ for comparing different raster map tiles.

If you are ready to use vector map tiles, you can also use https://openmaptiles.org/languages.

Comment: On https://openstreetmap.org you can also switch to the Cycle Map or Transport Map via the layer switcher on the right. They show both local as well as the english labels, if available.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use openstreetmap.de's map style and extensions to do that.

This OSM diary comment https://www.openstreetmap.org/user/%C3%98ukasz/diary/41907#comment39112 provides some how-to information and links, including a link to a video (given at a German conference, but in English).